Who is Mr Dick?
In David Copperfield, Betsey Trotwood says this about the man who lives with her:

"Mr. Dick is a sort of distant connection of mine; it doesn't matter how; I needn't enter into that."
Dickens, Charles. David Copperfield. 1850. Introduction by David Gates. Notes by Nitin Govil. New York: Modern Library, 2000. p. 192.

Do we ever find out more about this connection? What is Mr Dick's relation to Miss Trotwood?

I don't think we do. The point is that he is someone she knew of who would probably have ended up in a mental institution if she hadn't offered him a home and tolerated his eccentricities.
